# Importing images via webpack's 'url-loader' breaks output on IE11

Tags: javascript, webpack, internet-explorer-11

I have a simple yet daunting problem. I am using webpack's `url-loader` to import a png.

**webpack.config.js**

```
{
    test: /\.png$/,
    loader: 'url-loader'
}
```

**index.js**

```
import * as myImage from './img.png';

let img = new Image();
img.src = myImage.default;
```

This method of importing images works on Chrome, Opera, and Firefox. IE11 however, does not render my scene.

I am using the image as a texture in my WebGL context, but I want this question to be focused on webpack and it's aforementioned `url-loader`. I can confirm the texture is being applied correctly,it was working fine in IE11 before introducing webpack and `url-loader`. I attempted to use `file-loader`, but I get a 404 return code.

Is there a reason IE11 acts so unexpected when loading an image with `url-loader`? Am I missing documentation that specifies `url-loader`'s incompatibility with IE11?

[Here](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/url-loader/) is the doc I referenced.

Comment: `I attempted to use file-loader, but I get a 404 return code.`   I would suggest you find out why..  What backend you using?.

Comment: @Keith Right now, I'm just using the dev server that comes bundled with WebStorm.

Comment: I suggest you to use network tab of developer tools and also use some tool like fiddler to get more information about the issue. Check the image source and compare those data with other browsers. It can give some idea and help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Are you loading your webpack assets from the root dir?..  If not you will likely want to set the `publicPath` so they line up.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT So in the network tab of IE11's inspection I found that the PNG is not being loaded. In Chrome and Opera it is being loaded. What does this mean?

Comment: @Keith I am loading the png from an assets folder located in the root directory. Is setting the publicPath something IE11 specific?

Comment: `something IE11 specific?`  It shouldn't be, but it's maybe a caching issue.  IOW: at some point while using Chrome you did have the assets available at the root.   Without the `publicPath`, the `file-loader` will try to load from the root,.  `/somefile.png`, and that's maybe getting you the 404, when instead it should be loading `/assets/somefile.png` etc.

Comment: @Keith I set the publicPath `publicPath: 'assets'`, and I still get the 404 request code when using `file-loader`. I see the hashed png in my file directory but when chrome requests for it, webstorm tells chrome the image is not here. This is also the case if I use `http-server` in my terminal.

Comment: Do you mean issue is also producible using chrome browser? If yes than it may not be specifically related with IE and issue can be related with your app.